# How can I remove Telegraph from Firefox address bar suggestions?

Tags: firefox

I know how to remove a particular URL or whole website from the Firefox address bar suggestions ([for instance](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-address-bar-suggestions), going to the history and removing it from there, or right in the address bar suggestion list, highlight the "bad" line and press shift+delete).

However, it seems that Telegraph[dot]co[cot]uk is hard-coded and I can't get rid of it that way. This is highly annoying, as I often use the Telegram website, and despite visiting it often and putting it in my favorites, the bloody telegraph website comes as the top suggestion as I type the whole name... (as you can see, it's the very same name until the last couple of letters)

Is there any way to get rid of this address bar suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to `about:config` in the address bar
- If required, click the "Accept the Risk and Continue" button
- search for: "sponsored"
- To toggle an a value to false, double click it

I would recommend trying

`browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.showSponsored`

`browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.showSponsoredTopSites`

`browser.urlbar.sponsoredTopSites`

If that didn't work, then:

- Make sure telegraph.co.uk is not in your bookmarks and not in your history and not in your open tabs
- In the menu, go to Settings
- Click on Privacy & Security on the left hand side
- Scroll down to the Address Bar section
- Unselect "Shortcuts"
- Unselect "Top Sites"

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately those were already false :/ In the process, I also found services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.showSponsored and services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.showSponsoredTopSites, which were true and I set to false. But Telegraph is still showing...

Comment: Hm, weird. I added another option. @user14764

Comment: Well that's interesting. I found "shortcuts" here, but not "top sites". Disabling shortcuts didn't help, so I tried everything else in this list: eventually, I found that disabling "bookmarks" did the trick. But this is weird, I don't have Telegraph in my bookmarks and unlike all other bookmarks it doesn't have a blue star... I wonder what the hell is going on here :s

Comment: @user14764 And if you press Ctrl-Shift-O to see all bookmarks, select "All Bookmarks" on the left hand side, and then search for "telegr" in the top right corner? It's not that I don't believe you; its just a very weird situation.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the culprit: I do have a bookmark for a particular article from the Telegraph. It is not the URL that appears in the suggestions though: the bookmarked article is, say "telegraphcouk/some/path/", and what I get as a top suggestion is just "telegraphcouk/". So I guess my question becomes: how do I prevent a very rarely accessed bookmark from causing its top domain to appear as a top suggestion... (also, why does it still come on top of another one that I access daily)

Comment: @user14764 You should probably post a new question to inquire about that. But to be honest, the best solution is to simply delete the bookmark to that Telegraph article.